# fstream produces REALLY weird behavior

Tags: c++, debugging, fstream

When I write a double to a filestream, then write an integer, the integer gets appended to the double as extra digits, and I have no idea why it happens. Could someone please explain this for me? Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream s("test.bin", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    s << 3.14;
    int n = 36;
    s << n;
    s.seekp(0);
    double d;
    s >> d;
    printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

**What I expect to happen:**

- The program opens a file called test.bin
- It writes the value `3.14` to the file (8 bytes)
- It writes the value `36` to the file (4 bytes)
- It skips back to the beginning of the buffer
- It reads a double-type value (8 bytes)
- It prints the value (displaying `3.140000`)

**What actually happens:**
The program outputs `3.143600` - I have absolutely no idea why this happens. It makes zero sense. If I change the initial value, say from `3.14` to `18.3204`, then it outputs `18.320436`. What's happening?

Comment: use `std::cout` rather than some output file stream. Then ask yourself how you would  decide, were you a simple `double` extraction algorithm, where to *stop* reading digits. You have no whitespace between your output `double` and your output `int`. You realize this is *formatted* output, *right* ?

Comment: Doesn't it write the double value as 8 pure bytes?

Comment: No, `<<` performs formatted output, not binary output, even with `std::fstream::binary`.

Comment: If you want raw platform-dependent octets written out raw, use the `write` and `read` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It writes the value 3.14 to the file (8 bytes)
>   It writes the value 36 to the file (4 bytes)

This is not what happens. `>>` and `<<` and friends read and write values in human-readable form.

`s << 3.14;` writes the digit 3, a full stop, the digit 1, and the digit 4 to the file (4 ASCII characters).
`s << 36;` writes the digit 3, and the digit 6 to the file (2 ASCII characters).

The file then contains 6 ASCII characters: a 3, a full stop, a 1, a 4, a 3, and a 6. Or as any normal person would write it: it contains `3.1436`.

`s >> d;` reads a number, by characters from the file until it finds a character that doesn't look like a number, and then converting the characters it read into a number (the same way they'd be converted if you typed them into `cin`). It reads 3, full stop, 1, 4, 3, 6, and then produces the number 3.1436.

Answer (score 0):

When operating on streams, `<<` and `>>` perform formatted access. Ignoring the behind -the-scenes voodoo, `<<` writes strings and `>>` reads strings. So

```
s << 3.14;`
```

turns 3.14 into a string and writes the string to the file. Same with `s << n;`.

You now have a file containing the characters "3.1436".

```
s >> d;
```

reads the file as a string looking for separating whitespace or any other character that cannot be transformed into a double value.  Since there is nothing separating 3.14 and 36 in the file, 3.1436 is read back in as a single number.

What you need to do is use raw, unformatted reads and writes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream s("test.bin",
                   std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc |
                       std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    double d = 3.14;
    int n = 36;
    if (s.write((char*) &d, sizeof(d)) &&
        s.write((char*) &n, sizeof(n)))
    { 
        s.seekp(0);
        if (s.read((char*) &d, sizeof(d)))
        { 
            std::cout << d;
        }
        else 
        { 
             std::cerr << "failed to read\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
         std::cerr << "failed to write\n";
    }
}
```

Always test the IO to make sure it succeeded.

Also be warned that this isn't all that portable. A file written on one machine is not guaranteed to be readable on another without more care. `int`s may be different sizes and Beware [the endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) my son! The order that bytes...

[Documentation on `write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)

[Documentation on `read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)